# Workflow "SendAndReceiveActivity" is not calling WCF method

Tags: wcf, workflow

Following is the exact flow in my application:
1) A workflow (.xmalx) has Pick, within that there is Pick branch..
2) A pick branch has a receive activity - which gets called from an External WCF service with appropriate parameter.
3) There is a "SendAndReceiveActivity" after the receive activity, wherein Send activity is targeting to an operation in WCF service with the same parameters it received in Receive activity.

3rs step is the place where the things fail.. its just not hitting WCF method.. what could be the reason possible? I have double-checked endpoints, configurations, contracts and everything.. not sure, what I am missing.. 
Or else, anyone having an idea of how can we debug a WCF call from Workflow?